# Run exe in zip without extracting

Tags: powershell, zip

I have a .zip containing an installer (setup.exe and associated files).
How can I run `setup.exe` in a PowerShell script without extracting the zip?

Also, I need to pass command line parameters to setup.exe.

I tried

```
& 'C:\myzip.zip\setup.exe'
```

but I get an error

> ... not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

This opens the exe:

```
explorer 'C:\myzip.zip\setup.exe'
```

but I cannot pass parameters.

Comment: You can't. You will have to extract the content of the zip before using it - at least temporarily.

Comment: On Linux ZIP files and other compressed formats can be mounted to the file system. That's a scenario where binaries could be run without *explicitly* extracting first. I believe there are utilities for Windows that can mount compressed files in similar fashion, although I don't know any offhand.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1531318/why-is-it-not-recommended-to-run-a-exe-file-directly-from-a-zip-file

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not possible. You must extract the zip file in order to be able to run the executable. The `explorer` statement only works because the Windows Explorer does the extraction transparently in the background.

What you can do is write a custom function to encapsulate extraction, invocation, and cleanup.

```
function Invoke-Installer {
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -LiteralPath $_})]
        [string[]]$Path,

        [Parameter(Manatory=$false)]
        [string[]]$ArgumentList = @()
    )

    Begin {
        Add-Type -Assembly System.IO.Compression.FileSystem
    }

    Process {
        $Path | ForEach-Object {
            $zip, $exe = $_ -split '(?<=\.zip)\\+', 2

            if (-not $exe) { throw "Invalid installer path: ${_}" }

            $tempdir = Join-Path $env:TEMP [IO.File]::GetFileName($zip)
            [IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zip, $tempdir)

            $installer = Join-Path $tempdir $exe
            & $installer @ArgumentList

            Remove-Item $tempdir -Recurse -Force
        }
    }
}

Invoke-Installer 'C:\myzip.zip\setup.exe' 'arg1', 'arg2', ...
```

Note that this requires .Net Framework v4.5 or newer.

Comment: Actually, on my own computer, if you put an exe without any external file dependencies, you can run it within the zip by double clicking, and even using java you can technically extract the file location, I forget how, it was a while back that I did it. But if it does have files that should exist within a folder with it, it will throw errors because the file cannot collect the dependencies :/